# How to debug on device

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I have an Ionic app that I can run and debug using the Ripple emulator launched from Visual Studio 2015.

I can also run it on my Android device if I "Start without debugging".

Unfortunately, something that works on the emulator doesn't work on the device, so I need to debug on the device.

This is where I start hitting problems. Visual Studio hangs at "Installing app on device..." - unless I uninstall the app that was installed when I ran without debugging.

When I do that, the app runs but it doesn't hit any breakpoints and Visual Studio stops responding. After "LAUNCH SUCCESS" I have this message:

> Command finished with error code 0: cmd /s /c
>   ""C:.....\android\cordova\run.bat --nobuild --device --debug

So...how to get debugging working on the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tryied with chrome inspector? Plug your phone with the app installed, open it, open your chrome and type in the nav bar `chrome://inspect`

Comment: I haven't. I've had a (very) quick look, it might be useful, but it looks like it's for debugging websites. Do you know if this will work with an Ionic/ Apache Cordova app? Link I looked at: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging

Comment: Yes, I use it for debugging cordova apps in real devices. `chrome://inspects` shows you devices recogniced by adb. then you can select your device and debug it

Comment: Tried `chrome://inpects` as per the link I found. Chrome and com.facebook.katana are listed, under "Devices" but my app isn't. I installed my app using `ionic run android` from a command line. Is there something else I have to do to get it "recognised by adb"?

Comment: It's about a year since I had this problem, but I'm back with a need to debug on a device again, and VS2015 still hangs every time. I can't remember what I ended up doing last time, but this time I simply deployed the app using "Start without debugging" and now I'm using `chrome://inspect` with my Ionic app

Answer (score 1):

Like Del mentioned earlier, you can use Chrome and type `chrome://inspect` in the navigation bar to debug your app via USB. 
Make sure your device has Enable Remote Debugging enabled in the developer tools.

But I also suggest you try emulating a mobile device with a tool like thee [Ripple Emulator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta) extension for Chrome, which provides additional mobile feature simulation like:

- Touch events
- User agent
- Geo-location spoofing (with GPS delay & failure events)
- Accelerator spoofing
- Etc.

There are other tools that provide similar functionality.

These do of course work with Cordova apps as you mentioned in a comment.

Finally, if you are willing to buy an tool, I can suggest you try [Telerik's AppBuilder](http://www.telerik.com/appbuilder) plugin for Visual Studio. This tool allows you to deploy your app and debug it through Visual Studio. The debug interface looks similar to that of Chrome, where you can view your Console, Resources, Network, Timeline and Elements.

Comment: "I have an Ionic app that I can run and debug using the Ripple emulator launched from Visual Studio 2015...Unfortunately, something that works on the emulator doesn't work on the device, so I need to debug on the device."

Comment: @Colin I've updated my answer, please see the final paragraph. Also, do you mind saying what works on the emulator but not on your device?

Comment: AppBuilder does look interesting, but Tools for Apache Cordova claim that I can deploy and debug my app through Visual Studio, at least on Android and Windows. What does AppBuilder bring to the table? And will fix my problem? Maybe I should take a trial....As for what is not working - it is an angular directive `ng-click`. Should be easy to diagnose once I can set breakpoints

Comment: I can't comment on Tools for Apache Cordova as I haven't used it yet. It sounds very similar to AppBuilder. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I put the following line of code in the .js file right before the line of code that I have placed the breakpoint. This seems to give the application to stop for a moment and see the breakpoint.

```
alert("put whatever you want in here");
```

I hope this helps you as well.