# What version of Cordova do I have and how should I fix it?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

In a command line I type `cordova -v` and it tells me I have `3.6.3-0.2.13`
Also, if I type `ionic lib` it tells me that my Local Ionic Version is `1.0.0-beta.13` but the latest version is `1.1.0`

When I open my "Tools for Apache Cordova" project in Visual Studio 2015 and look at Platforms, the version for the Cordova CLI that will be used to build the project is specified as `4.3.0`

When I Debug -> Start without debugging, in the output window I see the following text: `------ Cordova tools 4.3.0 already installed`

Yesterday, in Visual Studio 2015 I used Tools -> Extensions and Updates to update Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova, but clearly that doesn't upgrade Ionic.

I am having some [problems with my environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256552/how-to-debug-on-device/33260238#33260238) and would appreciate guidance on how to get it set up properly.

Should I update Ionic via the command line? Will that also update Cordova or should I do that separately? Is that likely to break any other dependencies? Why does Visual Studio say 4.3.0 is installed but the command line says 3.6.3-0.2.13? Or are these two different beasts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `cordova -v`, you get the globally installed version of cordova, which on my machine is described by a `package.json` file located in `C:\Users\Colin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova`

I also have a `package.json` file in
`C:\Users\Colin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova\4.3.0\node_modules\cordova` - and that is the one VS2015 was using because my `taco.json` file contains `"cordova-cli": "4.3.0"`.

I re-installed the global ionic CLI and cordova using

```
npm uninstall –g ionic
npm uninstall –g cordova
npm install –g cordova ionic
```

Now when I type `cordova -v`, I'm told my global version is `5.3.3`

To make VS2015 also use `5.3.3`, I double-clicked on the `config.xml` and changed the value on the Platforms page from `4.3.0` to `5.3.3`, then I ran a build. During the build I got a message `Installing Cordova tools cordova@5.3.3 for project from npm`. Now I have a `package.json` file at `C:\Users\Colin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova\5.3.3\node_modules\cordova`

Subsequent builds give a message `Cordova tools 5.3.3 already installed`

The other thing I found confusing is the difference between the Ionic CLI and the Ionic Library.

When you type `ionic -v` that tells you the version of the CLI (now `1.7.7` on my machine).

`ionic lib` tells you the version of the ionic javascript library installed in the `www/lib/ionic` folder - which on my machine is now `1.1.0` after I ran `ionic lib update` in my project folder

Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33262777/150342

Answer (score 2):

Ionic depends on cordova. (At least for mobile development) They can (and must) be updated separatly.

As cordova has recently changed to the gradle build system updating may cause issues. Especially regarding installed plugins.

If you updated cordova with `npm update -g cordova --save` then you should also update the platforms in your project folder with `cordova platform update <your_platform>`

Ionic CLI is updated by typing `npm update -g ionic --save` after that you can update the ionic libs in your project folder with `ionic lib update`

I can't say anything regarding your Visual Studio problem as I don't use it. But maybe VS comes with an included version of cordova?